# How can I backup SE comment debate before I get a moderator to clean it up?

Tags: support, comments

It happens that a comment thread gets interesting. To the participants, that is, not other visitors. 10+ comments are bad thing (though on Meta's it's different and my humble opinion is that Meta is not suitable for Q&A format - well we actually welcome questions that can lead to a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)!).

But you might want to keep the debate with the links working (instead of printing screen). So how you would do that before you make the question clean again?

I could use Firebug to fetch appropriate HTML, but might there be a better option? Ideally one that would not allow you to modify the comments after the originals have been lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the page at http://archive.org/web/. That's a web application created for saving a specific page at a specific time. That might be useful in this case. But keep in mind that the saved page will be visible for everyone, not just for you. This way won't help though if the comment thread is long and collapsed, as you said in your comment.

If you don't want to use that, you don't need Firebug to fetch the HTML, web browsers have the ability to save web pages on your computer.

If you save the files on your disk and one of the participants of the discussion claims that the backup is fake, contact a ♦ moderator. Moderators have the ability to see deleted comments.

Comment: I'm pretty comfortable with everybody seeing it. The thing is that long discussion uses AJAX to load (eg. it's not downloaded when you load the page, or so I think), therefore the rest might not get archived. Maybe this will be fixed if the site recognises that archive.org does not use javascript.

Comment: @TomášZato I think the comment thread gets saved entirely if you save it after you load all comments. I'm not entirely sure, but it's worth a try.

Comment: That [doesn't apply to the wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20141124163322/http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/5829/does-mental-rigidity-cause-psychological-problems#) though. In case someone has related with me in an unpleasant way he might say my backup is false. I know I wouldn't cheat that way but nobody else does... I'd like if you'd avoid discussing anything in the related thread here, no matter what do you think about it. I'm not here to complain that somebody doesn't agree with me.

Comment: @TomášZato I see. I expanded my answer: you can contact a moderator because they can see deleted comments.

Comment: Thank you. Since I it seems that reasons for contacting a moderator might be disputable (+8/-10) I think I should rather suppress my ego and just flag the question along with the flame. Especially on a Beta site where moderators are incredibly overwhelmed.

Answer (score 3):

**Screen Shot**

A screen shot is worth a thousand words

[image]

---

**Save the page**

Alternatively, you could save the page using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>. This would capture everything on the page at that instant including comments, links, etc. Although any locally referenced materials (possibly including scripts, css, and images) will not show up when the page is opened. In extreme cases these can be modified to again include the local context.

Comment: Has the disadvantage that the links don't work any more. There might be useful links in the comments, even though not on-topic.

Comment: There could be, and they wouldn't be obvious if they were in `[]()` format so that is a good point. However, if there are links which are useful most people just bookmark them.

Comment: I have tons of bookmarks but I still keep googling things I've bookmarked. But a discussion, that you don't forget. As well it contains more words you can search by (google or HDD). Ultimately, I see no problem with faking a screenshot.

Comment: I might be overly critic but please know that I appreciate your courage to point out the obvious (anybody who's sincere to himself knows it needs courage), as the obvious is what I often miss.

Comment: @TomášZato - The screenshot is largely viable (and often used) for saving these comment segments. They show up on meta a lot. However, if you really want the full context preserved, then you can simply save the entire page, html scripts and all, and open that at a later time.

Answer (score 2):

I also noticed that moderator can, upon demand, move whole thread to chat. That way it will last.

However this might need to take place after the debate as most users won't join a chat with you, probably afraid that their awesome posts won't be read by other users.

Comment: This doesn't have to be done by moderators manually afaik. The only thing mods really *"need"* to do is cleaning the comments from under the post after the move to chat is done.. be aware that the chat is "eternally" available as soon as a room gets more than 10 messages.